# Looping all JTree nodes and get the objects in each node

Tags: java, swing, jtree, classcastexception

I have this `JTree`:
[image]

I have inserted in each node `Element` type object (a class I have created)
but when I want to loop the tree to get the objects from these nodes the console shows me:

```
ClassCastException (java.lang.String cannot be cast to swing.drawing.Element)
```

This is my loop code:

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) myJTree.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
Enumeration e = parent.depthFirstEnumeration();
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
  DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
  Element element = (Element) node.getUserObject();
  System.out.println(" --> Type: "+element.getType()+" , pos in list: "+element.getPostionInList());
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @SlimenTunis It would help if you provide the code how you filled the tree. It seems you have added a `String` to the tree, not just `swing.drawing.Element`s.